# Why am I getting this error when trying to use immutability helper? "...does not provide an export named 'default'"

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am using Vite and vanilla Javascript and I am trying to learn how to use react-dnd, which uses the immutability-helper package. However, I keep getting this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/immutability-helper/index.js?v=f0743135' does not provide an export named 'default'

I have installed the latest immutability-helper and I am importing it the following way: import update from "immutability-helper";

Alternatively, I have tried: import * as update from "immutability-helper";
which gives me this error:
index.js?v=f0743135:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at index.js?v=f0743135:2:23

I had a look at the index.js file in the immutability-helper package, but I'm a beginner in Javascript language so I don't understand what is wrong. I'm not sure if this would help but the following snippets of code are from the file, unmodified

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

//lines of code

var Context = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Context() {
        this.commands = assign({}, defaultCommands);
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
        // Deprecated: update.extend, update.isEquals and update.newContext
        this.update.extend = this.extend = this.extend.bind(this);
        this.update.isEquals = function (x, y) { return x === y; };
        this.update.newContext = function () { return new Context().update; };
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Context.prototype, "isEquals", {
        get: function () {
            return this.update.isEquals;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this.update.isEquals = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    Context.prototype.extend = function (directive, fn) {
        this.commands[directive] = fn;
    };
    Context.prototype.update = function (object, $spec) {
        var _this = this;
        var spec = (typeof $spec === 'function') ? { $apply: $spec } : $spec;
        if (!(Array.isArray(object) && Array.isArray(spec))) {
            invariant(!Array.isArray(spec), function () { return "update(): You provided an invalid spec to update(). The spec may " +
                "not contain an array except as the value of $set, $push, $unshift, " +
                "$splice or any custom command allowing an array value."; });

//more lines

exports.Context = Context;

//more lines
};
var defaultContext = new Context();
exports.isEquals = defaultContext.update.isEquals;
exports.extend = defaultContext.extend;
exports.default = defaultContext.update;
// @ts-ignore
exports.default.default = module.exports = assign(exports.default, exports);
// invariants

//final lines of code
```